# Increment value on Firestore with FieldValue on Vue App

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently trying to update a value on a document at my firestore database by 1. After searching a while I found about the FieldValue.increment(1). My goal is to have a form with 2 fields (Host/Scout) and I'll input on those fields the name of a person that will need to get their host or scout value incremented. This is how my vue component looks like

```
<template>
  <div class="add-wave">
    <h3>Add Wave</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <form @click.prevent="addwave()" class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input type="text" v-model="host" />
            <label class="active">Host</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input type="text" v-model="scout" />
            <label class="active">Scout</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
        <router-link to="/member" class="btn grey">Cancel</router-link>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import db from "../data/firebaseInit";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      host: null,
      scout: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addwave() {
      db.collection("members")
        .where("name", "==", this.$route.params.host)
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            doc.ref
              .update({
                host: db.FieldValue.increment(1)
              })
              .then(() => {
                this.$router.push({
                  name: "member",
                  params: { name: this.name }
                });
              });
          });
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Everything compiles but whenever I try input a name at each input field I get an error "FirebaseError: "Function Query.where() requires a valid third argument, but it was undefined."

I'm don't know why I'm getting this error or how I can fix it. Could anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: What is the value of `this.$route.params.host` right before the where call?  Perhaps you mean `this.host`?

Comment: It's undefined, that's probably my problem, but I really don't know what I'm supposed to replace it with.

edit: I replaced with this.host and it seems to fix this error but when I click submit I get this error now "TypeError: _data_firebaseInit__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.FieldValue is undefined"

Comment: Can you share the content of your `firebaseInit` file?

Comment: `FieldValue` is in the `firebase.firestore` namespace, but notably is _not_ accessable as part of `firebase.firestore()`, assuming `db` is `firebase.firestore()` try using `firebase.firestore.FieldValue` instead.

Comment: @nicholasfc Can you also show the URL you use to call this vue.js component

Comment: @renaud my firebaseInit content
```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import firebaseConfig from "./firebaseConfig";
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebaseApp.firestore();
```

and the url is localhost:8080/wave

@robsiemb
when I change from db to firebase.firestore I got a linter error "error: 'firebase' is not defined (no-undef)"

Comment: @robsiemb Looks like you were right. The correct syntax is `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment()`. You can't get the "static" `FieldValue` from the on-demand created `FirebaseApp` instance.

Comment: @nicholasfc you'll need to import the firebase symbol of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the problem of `FieldValue.increment(1)`, you need to export `FieldValue` in your `firebaseInit` file, as follows:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"; 
import "firebase/firestore"; 
import firebaseConfig from "./firebaseConfig"; 

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebase.firestore();
const fv = firebase.firestore.FieldValue;

export { db, fv };
```

Then, in your component you do:

```
import {db, fv} from "../data/firebaseInit";

//....
fv.increment(1)
```

---

For the second problem, you will read in the vue router [doc](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties) that:

> $route.params
>
> An object that contains key/value pairs of dynamic segments and star segments. If there are no params the value will be an empty object.

Since you are not passing any key/value pairs in your URL you need to use another Route object property, i.e. `$route.path`

> $route.path
>
> A string that equals the path of the current route, always resolved as an absolute path. e.g. "/foo/bar".

as follows:

```
  db.collection("members")
    .where("name", "==", this.$route.path.substr(1))
    .get()
    ...
```

Comment: The fix on the firebaseInit fixed the error for me. It wasn't mentioned on the firebase docs and that's why I didn't do it in the first place.

The $route.params fix was simple to just change it to this.host as another user mentioned. I copied that part from another component and forgot to update it accordingly.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I'm getting an error of ````firebaseApp is declared but never used````. Where did you use the firebaseApp in your project? @RenaudTarnec

Comment: @TylerMorales You can just do `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);`. Doing `const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);`is interesting if you want to call specific methods of the firebase app instance. BTW, please accept and upvote my answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63666761/3371862), if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 2 issues with the code as it stands:

- `this.$route.params.host` should probably be `this.host`, as that is where Vue will bind the host parameter.  This is the immediate answer to your initial question.
- Assuming `db` is created from `firebase.firestore()`, it is not a valid way to reference the static `FieldValue` for the `increment` function.  You need to get it directly as `firebase.firestore.FieldValue`.  You will need to in some way import this symbol into your code, since right now `firebase` isn't accessible as it only exists in the `firebaseInit` module.

One way to do this import is to just add this at the top of your `<script>` section (there's another way documented in another answer):

`import firebase from "firebase/app";`

Note also that counters may eventually not scale, given the per-document update rate limit of 1-update-per-second.  The firebase documentation has a [solution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) for how to build counters distributed across multiple documents once you outgrow this solution.  Regardless, this also shows proper use of `increment` generally.

Comment: Thank you so much. the this.$route.params.host was wrong since I copied it from another component and forgot to fix. Changing to this.host fixed the problem. I also know the 1 update-per-second limit and will see the solution you mentioned.

The way you were mentioning to fix the fieldvalue problem was giving me an error but another user helped me with it.

Again, thank you so much for helping