# Firebase's update function lags behind button click on browser

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a real time voting app in Vue using firebase to store the number of votes. I am able to create the data base and increment the number of votes, as well as display the most up to date votes from the database to my application. However, when I click my button to update the number of votes by one, the vote is only increased in the browser and not on firebase.

Am I using the update function wrong?

```js
...methods:{
upVotePingu() {
      let pingu = db.collection('canidates').doc('pingu')

      // Atomically increment the population of the city by 50.
      pingu.set({
        votes: this.pingu.votes++
      })

      console.log('voted')
    }
```

```js
...mounted(){
db.collection('canidates')
      .get()
      .then(query => {
        query.forEach(doc => {
          const dbVote = {
            vote: doc.data().votes
          }
          this.pingu.votes = dbVote.vote
          console.log(this.pingu.votes)
        })
      })
```

```js
<button @click="upVotePingu">Vote</button>
```

```js
data() {
    return {
      pingu: {
        votes: 0
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do as follows:

```
  this.pingu.votes++
  pingu.set({
    votes: this.pingu.votes
  })
```

---

In addition, note that, to increment the value of a field, it is safer to use `FieldValue.increment`, see https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-increment

Comment: Hi @TylerMorales, did you have the time to test the proposed answer? If it gives you the solution to your problem, please accept it. Thx.